# Realm Object in Completion Handler: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am developing an SDK that basically writes wrapper methods hiding API calls and returns data objects in completion Handler:

```swift
public static func getDogs(token: String?, completionhandler: @escaping (Int?, [Dog]?) -> Void) {
}
```

Dogs are Realm Objects:

```swift
public class Dog: Object {
    @objc public dynamic var name: String?
    @objc public dynamic var age: Int = 0
}
```

Now when I try to access Dogs in a call to getDogs,

```swift
getDogs(token: token) { status, dogs in
    \\ Access Dog[0]
}
```

As expected, I get the RealmException:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'

Now, How can I pass such a list of Realm objects in a completion handler and access it later without getting this exception? I know of `ThreadSafeReference` but I do not want end user to read a manual of third party dependency before being able to use the SDK. What should be the best practice here? Obviously, I cannot send a list of Realm objects. Also from the design considerations for an independent framework, I should not assume that our end users should know Realm apriori. Realm support should be good to have and not foremost.

Another option that I have is to keep two copies of the same data model: a normal object and a Realm object. But this will increase the parsing time.

Comment: Call the completion handler on the same thread on which the `getDogs...` method is called

Comment: Realm object (the Realm object instance itself) has to be accessed in the same thread in which they were initialized.

Comment: @Roberto While that is a true statement, there's nothing in the question showing that the Realm objects are being accessed on a different thread. OP: while I understand your question, there's not enough code to know where you're going wrong. You don't need to worry about threading unless you are *doing* threading; using background threads for tasks etc and there's nothing in your code showing that. Can you provide an example of where you're getting that error? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay Since the error indicates an exception due to an access from an incorrect thread, I think it is safe to assume that he is using threads in one or another way.

Comment: @jay many thanks for your comment. I understand that my post doesn’t indicate clearly how the realm objects are shared across threads. In order to make post simple and readable, sorry for missing out details. I will add them asap.

Comment: @Roberto Agreed. I wanted to dig in a bit to see why and how they are being used across threads in case that was the actual issue or if it could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Realm documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/):

> Instances of RLMRealm, RLMResults, or RLMArray, or managed instances of RLMObject are thread-confined, meaning that they can only be used on the thread on which they were created, otherwise an exception is thrown

In order to avoid this exception, you should create a Realm instance every time you need one and make sure you're releasing it with an autorelease pool.

```
// Query and update from any thread
autoreleasepool {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
    try! realm.write {
        theDog!.age = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an accurate answer provided you are using threading. You do *not* need to wrap realm within an autorelease pool for every circumstance. Only if you are using using realm across threads or using multiple Realm files that need to be deallocated when switching.